# Is there any better way to ignore headers in file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I wrote a file reading code file in python.But I did not like my approach such  as using `next(iter)` to ignore headers. I need some suggestions to improve this code.

Format of file:

```
OrderId, OrderName
1, Washing powder
2, Diaper
3, Cola
4, ToothPaste
5, Handfree
```

Code:

```
def set_order_details(self):

    order_record = self.order_file.readlines()

    iter_order = iter(order_record)
    next(iter_order) #For removing Headers

    for order_detail in iter_order:
        order_and_detail = order_detail.rstrip().split(',')

        if len(order_and_detail) == 2:
            self.order_dictionary[(order_and_detail[0])] = OrderDepth(order_and_detail[1])

    return self.order_dictionary


class OrderDepth:
    def __init__(self, order):
        self.order = order
        self.depth = 0
```

Comment: if your header is always one line and always the first line, then the `next()` approach is fine. (side note: the `.readlines()` call is likely unnecessary, you can iterate the file handle)

Comment: Why is this tagged `numpy`? And python already has [this hammer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) built in, so why are you cobbling together your own hammer out of a twig, a rock and a piece of string?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks for notifying me, I removed the tag the of numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [CSV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, so processing it with an instance of the built-in [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class makes sense and would allow you to simplify your code by automatically skipping the header and also makes the code a little more readable.

Note, too, that you don't need to use `iter()` at all, because, like files, `csv.DictReader` instances are already iterable.

Since your example code doesn't contain a complete class, I made up one for demonstration purposes and also added a `__repr__()` method to the `OrderDepth` class to make printing them more readable.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint


class OrderDepth:
    def __init__(self, order, depth=0):
        self.order = order
        self.depth = depth

    def __repr__(self):
        classname = self.__class__.__name__
        return f'{classname}(order={self.order!r}, depth={self.depth})'


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.csv_file = open(filename, 'r', newline='')
        self.order_file = csv.DictReader(self.csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)

    def set_order_details(self):
        self.order_dictionary = {}
        for order_detail in self.order_file:
            if len(order_detail) == 2:
                od = OrderDepth(order_detail['OrderName'])
                self.order_dictionary[order_detail['OrderId']] = od
        return self.order_dictionary


foo = Foo("orders.csv")
order_dictionary = foo.set_order_details()
pprint(order_dictionary)
```

Sample output:

```
{'1': OrderDepth(order='Washing powder', depth=0),
 '2': OrderDepth(order='Diaper', depth=0),
 '3': OrderDepth(order='Cola', depth=0),
 '4': OrderDepth(order='ToothPaste', depth=0),
 '5': OrderDepth(order='Handfree', depth=0)}
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def set_order_details(self):

        iter_order = iter(self.order_file.readlines()[1:])

        for order_detail in iter_order:
            order_and_detail = order_detail.rstrip().split(',')

            if len(order_and_detail) == 2:
                self.order_dictionary[(order_and_detail[0])] = OrderDepth(order_and_detail[1])

        return self.order_dictionary
```